# PHP form restricting options

Tags: php

I'm still new to PHP, so bear with me.  I think I'm on the right track, but I just can't quite figure it out.

The objective is to make a simple order form using radio buttons and checkboxes.  Their are restrictions though.  In this case, no chocolate sprinkles on chocolate ice cream, and no walnuts on peanut butter ice cream.  I've been trying for almost 4 hours now to figure out how to make it check for one, and then check for the other.

I appreciate any help.

HTML Code:

```
    <DOCTYPE xhtml>
    <head>
    <title>Lab 4 - Ice Cream</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lab4.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <h3>Ice Cream Order Form</h3>
    <hr>
    <form action="lab4.php" method="post">
    Please choose a flavor:
    <ul><li><input type="radio" name="flavor" value="Vanilla" checked="checked">Vanilla</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="flavor" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="flavor" value="Peanut Butter">Peanut Butter</li>
    </ul>

    Please choose your toppings:
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[0]" value="Cherries">Cherries</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[1]" value="Chocolate Sprinkles" id="chocsprink">Chocolate Sprinkles</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[2]" value="Pineapple">Pineapple</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="toppings[3]" value="Walnuts">Walnuts</li>
    <li><br /></li>
    <li><input id="submit" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"><input id="reset" type="Reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></li>

    <div id="note">
    <span>Please note: We are unable to put chocolate sprinkles on chocolate ice cream.        </span><br />
    <span>Please note: We are unable to put walnuts on peanut butter ice cream.</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Code:

```
    $toppings=$_POST['toppings'];
    $flavor=$_POST['flavor'];
    $break='<br>';

    if (isset($_POST['toppings[1]'])) { 
        $choc = True;}

    if (isset($_POST['flavor'])==Chocolate){
        $flav = True;}

    if($choc == True && $flav === True){
    echo 'We are sorry, but you can not put chocolate sprinkles on chocolate ice cream.';}

        else {
        echo 'Thank You. <br /><br ?>';
        echo 'Your order has been placed<br /><br />';
        echo '';
        echo "You have chosen the <u><b>$flavor</b></u> ice cream with the following toppings:<br />";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['toppings'])) {
        foreach($_POST['toppings'] as $alltoppings) {
            echo $alltoppings . $break;}}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
if (isset($_POST['flavor'])==Chocolate){
```

is wrong. [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks if the value is set, and returns a boolean. This also results in a warning that `Chocolate` is an undefined constant and that it will use the value as string.

If you want to check existence and its values, go like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['flavor']) && $_POST['flavor']=="Chocolate"){
```

In addition to that (as others have pointed out), you should reference your toppings differently:

```
if (isset($_POST['toppings'][1])) {
```

A word of advice, enable error reporting and display all errors. It will help you in making more robust scripts.

Comment: this is only applicable, if `Chocolate` is a constant - otherwise it would be `'Chocolate'`

Comment: When you say reference the toppings differently, do you mean giving them each their own names so I could use their individual identifiers?

Comment: @DustinSiebert no, I meant the syntax of the array indexer. Look closely on how you wrote it, and how I wrote it.

Comment: Beautiful.  I even over looked it with it right in front of my face. Lesson learned, thank you.